# Robust 24V alternator input circuit

Tags: circuit-protection

[image]

I need a bit of advice on the following proposals for interfacing an industrial mining truck's 24VAC alternator signal to a micro.  The frequency is DC to 1khz.  The voltage varies between 5 and 24V depending on the charging.  Its a very dirty signal and the return path is via the chassis ground of the truck.
I have 3 ideas but need some input on which one will work the best - robust is the name of the game here.

[image]

[image: IDEA2]

[image: IDEA3]

Any other ideas or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you measure a signal on low-side so it’s tied/connected with Gnd (not a Vcc) you should use a npn transitor with emitter on Gnd. An optocoupler is a good idea.

Comment: At what voltage level of input signal you want to switch an opto?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to start simple and add complexity where needed.

My first proposal is therefore to use an optocoupler with a single resistor on the input side, i.e. the optocoupler LED will be powered by the alternator voltage through the resistor. Maybe you need to limit the voltage with a Zener.